# XPath - how to select div that has a specific class, but only if it has a child div with a specific class inside iframe?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm scraping [this page](https://bbrauncareers-bbraun.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchRelation=keyword_all) with Python and Selenium. Specifically, I'm trying to scrape all the job search results (divs with job information), and as you can see, they're in a div element with a class `row`. However, because they don't have a class specific for them alone, but just have a generic class  `row`, I can't just get them by that alone.

This is what I tried, in an attempt to get an element with a class `row`, which has a child with a class `header`. But I think I'm using the contains wrong, and I have no idea how to fix it:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(@class,'row') and (contains(@class, 'header'))])")))
```

When I use the code above, I get the TimeoutException error, so I'm assuming it's looking for a div with both of those classes and failing to find it. Which is not what I had in mind.

How do I adjust the `contains` above to get what I need? Is it even possible to use this approach? Thanks!

Comment: Note that to test whether the class attribute has the value "row", you should write `[@class='row']`. Writing `[contains(@class, 'row')]` also matches (for example) `class="growth"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is placed in iframe.

To get an element from iframe you should switch to it's context first.

Frame has unique id `icims_content_iframe`

[Reference](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://bbrauncareers-bbraun.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchRelation=keyword_all&mobile=false&width=1168&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=120&jun1offset=180")
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'icims_content_iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

table_rows = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class*=JobsTable] .row"))
)

for row in table_rows:
    print(row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.title h2').text)

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Yup, I was already accessing the iFrame, but your suggestion is just top notch! Very clean and readable. Thank you so much, Yaroslavm.